# ¿Por qué mi peticion a traves de POSTMAN no llega a mi método y manda error de 404?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, postman, microservices

Tengo los siguientes metodos en mi controlador, el cual el primero sin problemas me muestra todo lo que hay en la tabla que estoy consultando, pero al probar el segundo método en POSTMAN me manda el siguiente error:

> {
> "timestamp": "2021-05-26T23:17:40.022+00:00",
> "status": 404,
> "error": "Not Found",
> "message": "",
> "path": "/consultarValores"
> }

```html
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/consultarValores")
public class ValoresTablaPrueba {
    
    @Autowired
    private ValoresTablaService valoresService;
    
    @GetMapping("/listar")
    public List<ValoresDto> consultarValores(){
        return valoresService.listarValores(); 
    }
    
    @GetMapping(path= {"/{fechInicio}", "/{fechFin}"})
    public List<ValoresDto> consultarValoresParam(@PathVariable("fechInicio") int fechInicio, @PathVariable("fechFin") int fechFinal){
        System.out.println("::ENTRA METODO");
        System.out.println("PRUEBA ENTRADA DE FEHCAS: " + " "+fechInicio + " " +fechFinal);
    return valoresService;.listarValoresParam(fechInicio, fechFinal); 
    }

}
```

ni siquiera entra al metodo por que no me manda lo que meti en el System y en el POSTMAN manda ese error, que me esta faltando o que puede estar mal? ya que el primer método si me manda resultados pero al filtrar por los parametros ya no

para probar en postman este es mi endpoint

> http://localhost:8080/consultarValores?fechInicio=20131013&fechFin=20131009

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucedes es que estás indicando que dos rutas caerían en el mismo método.

Para poder pasar varios parámetros puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma

```
@GetMapping
public List<ValoresDto> consultarValoresParam(@RequestParam("fechInicio") int fechInicio, @RequestParam("fechFin") int fechFinal){
        ....
```

Otra forma mas explicita sería

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", params = { "fechInicio", "fechFin" }, method = GET)
public List<ValoresDto> consultarValoresParam(@RequestParam("fechInicio") int fechInicio, @RequestParam("fechFin") int fechFinal){
        ....
```